# Estimate true probabilities from weighted sampling without replacement

Tags: probability, independence

Suppose we have a random event with $n$ outcomes, with (unknown) true probabilities $p_1, p_2, \dots, p_n$. We have performed a study of this event,  sampling it in batches of $k < n$. From this we have found a good estimation of $q_i$: the probability that outcome $i$ occurs in a batch of $k$ events.

However, there is a crucial issue with our study. **Each event $i$ can only occur once in a batch.** Once an event $i$ has occurred, that event's probability becomes $0$ for the remainder of the batch (and the rest of the probability distribution normalized to sum to $1$).

If we'd assume $\hat p_i = q_i$ then the most frequent outcomes are underestimated, and the lesser frequent overestimated. Can we do better, that is, find a good corrected estimate $\hat {\bf p}$ from $\bf q$ and $k$?

---

Note that we don't know the order of the events within each batch, otherwise we could use the first event as an unbiased indicator. Nevertheless even if we did know the order within each batch it would be nice to also use the information in the events after the first in each batch effectively and correctly.

Comment: How good is the MLE here?

Comment: This is a great question. You might want to give a look at this: https://forumserver.twoplustwo.com/15/poker-theory-amp-gto/new-algorithm-calculate-icm-large-tournaments-1098489/. This is like independent chip model, where you have to estimate the probability for a player to rank in a tournament given their stack size share ($p_i$ for you). You have to do the opposite inference: given how many times a player ranked in the first $k$ positions, estimate their stack size share.

Comment: The link above requires familiarity with ICM; here the wiki source for its definition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_Chip_Model

Answer (score 1):

It's a very interesting question. I will share an initial answer to your question, which I'm not convinced is the best answer possible.

Note that the probability of witnessing a sequence $a_1,\ldots,a_k$ of distinct elements of $[n] := \{1,\ldots,n\}$ sampled in this order is precisely
$$
P_{a_1,\ldots,a_k} := \prod_{i=1}^k \frac{p_{a_i}}{1-\sum_{r=1}^{i-1}p_{a_r}}.$$
Thus the probability of having the sample $A := \{a_1,\ldots,a_k\}$ in any order is
$$
\mu_A := \mu_A(p_1,\ldots,p_n) := \prod_{i=1}^k p_{a_i} \sum_{ \sigma \in \mathcal{S}_k}  \prod_{i=1}^r ( 1 - \sum_{r=1}^{i-1}p_{a_{\sigma(r)}} )^{-1},$$
where the sum is taken over the set of bijections $\mathcal{S}_k$ of $\{1,\ldots,k\}$. The numbers $\{\mu_A (p_1,\ldots,p_n) : [n]^{[k]} \}$ form a probability measure on the collection $[n]^{[k]}$ of size $k$ subsets of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$. This procedure then gives rise to a map $\Phi:\mathcal{P}([n]) \to \mathcal{P}([n]^{[k]})$ from the set of probability measures on $[n]$ to the set of probability measures on $[n]^{[k]}$.

Each round of our experiment constitutes choosing an element of $[n]^{[k]}$, with probability $\mu_A$ of choosing $A$. Thus we can estimate the $\mu_A$ in an unbiased fashion by letting
$$\hat{\mu_A} := \frac{1}{R} \# \{ \text{occurences of $A$ in $R$ rounds} \}.$$
We know that as $R$ tends to infinity, the each $\hat{\mu_A}$ converges to $\mu_A$ almost-surely. The question now is whether we can estimate $\{p_i\}$ from $\{\hat{\mu_A}\}$.

Consider the injectivity and surjectivity of $\Phi$. It is a simple exercise to show that $\Phi$ is injective, i.e. $$\mu_A(p_1,\ldots,p_n) = \mu_A(p_1',\ldots,p_n') \text{ for all $A$ in $[n]^{[k]}$} \implies (p_1,\ldots,p_n) = (p_1',\ldots,p_n').$$ To see this, we may use the fact that each $\mu_A(p_1,\ldots,p_n)$ is strictly increasing in any operation on probability measures on $[n]$ which increases at least one of $\{p_i : i \in A\}$ while decreasing at least one of $\{p_j :j \notin A\}$. On the other hand, $\Phi$ is not surjective; this can be seen from a dimension argument. As a result, I think it is the case that the estimators $\{\hat{\mu_A} : A \in [n]^{[k]}\}$ will likely not lie in the image of $\mu$.

However, an initial answer to your question might then be

1. Given estimates $\hat{\mu} := \{ \hat{\mu_A} : A \in [n]^k \}$, choose the closest element $\tilde{\mu}$ in the image of $\Phi$, where close is in a suitable sense (e.g. total variation).
2. Now, recalling that $\Phi$ is injective, let $\hat{p} := \Phi^{-1}(\tilde{\mu})$.

Then by the continuity of $\mu_A(p_1,\ldots,p_n)$ in the $p_i$ variables, and the  fact that $\hat{\mu_A} \to \mu_A$ almost-surely, $\hat{p} \to p$ almost-surely as the number of rounds $R$ tends to infinity. I'm not sure whether this estimator is unbiased.